# Could not get values while parsing the xml file using dom4j

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a xml using dom4j, I have tried some logic I could not get the complete data from the file.

See below my XML file:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System><Provider Name='Application Error'/>
        <EventID Qualifiers='0'>1000</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>100</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-07-29T04:33:30.000000000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>264</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>WIN-R8CUJUTBUMV</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>AppCrasher.exe</Data>
        <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
        <Data>55b239c6</Data>
        <Data>AppCrasher.exe</Data>
        <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
        <Data>55b239c6</Data>
        <Data>c0000005</Data>
        <Data>000113e8</Data>
        <Data>308</Data>
        <Data>01d0c9b7b7373caa</Data>
        <Data>C:\eGurkha\CrashLogTest_Script\AppCrasher x64\AppCrasher.exe</Data>
        <Data>C:\eGurkha\CrashLogTest_Script\AppCrasher x64\AppCrasher.exe</Data>
        <Data>f6135af5-35aa-11e5-b2fe-005056b27da4</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

This my java code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File("D:\\EventLog\\xml_op.xml");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            String line="",con_line="";
            int inc =0;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                con_line+=line;
            }
            System.out.println("Constructed Line = "+con_line);
            Document doc=DocumentHelper.parseText(con_line);
            System.out.println("Root Element = "+doc.getRootElement().getName());
            Element parent_ele = doc.getRootElement();
             for (Iterator i1 = parent_ele.elementIterator("System"); i1.hasNext();)
             {
                 Element Sys = (Element) i1.next();                
                 System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
                 System.out.println("Provider--> " + Sys.element("Provider").attributeValue("Name"));
                 System.out.println("EventID--> " + Sys.elementText("EventID"));
                 System.out.println("Level--> " + Sys.elementText("Level"));
                 System.out.println("Task--> " + Sys.elementText("Task"));
                 System.out.println("Keywords--> " + Sys.elementText("Keywords"));
                 System.out.println("TimeCreated--> " + Sys.element("TimeCreated").attributeValue("SystemTime"));
                 System.out.println("EventRecordID--> " + Sys.elementText("EventRecordID"));
                 System.out.println("Channel--> " + Sys.elementText("Channel"));
                 System.out.println("Computer--> " + Sys.elementText("Computer"));
                 System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
             }
             for (Iterator i1 = parent_ele.elementIterator("EventData"); i1.hasNext();)
             {
                 Element Sys = (Element) i1.next(); 
                 System.out.println("Data--> " + Sys.elementText("Data"));
             }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my output:

```
Constructed Line = <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>    <System><Provider Name='Application Error'/>        <EventID Qualifiers='0'>1000</EventID>      <Level>2</Level>        <Task>100</Task>        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>       <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-07-29T04:33:30.000000000Z'/>      <EventRecordID>264</EventRecordID>      <Channel>Application</Channel>      <Computer>WIN-R8CUJUTBUMV</Computer>        <Security/> </System>   <EventData>     <Data>AppCrasher.exe</Data>     <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>        <Data>55b239c6</Data>       <Data>AppCrasher.exe</Data>     <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>        <Data>55b239c6</Data>       <Data>c0000005</Data>       <Data>000113e8</Data>       <Data>308</Data>        <Data>01d0c9b7b7373caa</Data>       <Data>C:\eGurkha\CrashLogTest_Script\AppCrasher x64\AppCrasher.exe</Data>       <Data>C:\eGurkha\CrashLogTest_Script\AppCrasher x64\AppCrasher.exe</Data>       <Data>f6135af5-35aa-11e5-b2fe-005056b27da4</Data>   </EventData></Event>
Root Element = Event
------------------------------------------------
Provider--> Application Error
EventID--> 1000
Level--> 2
Task--> 100
Keywords--> 0x80000000000000
TimeCreated--> 2015-07-29T04:33:30.000000000Z
EventRecordID--> 264
Channel--> Application
Computer--> WIN-R8CUJUTBUMV
------------------------------------------------
Data--> AppCrasher.exe // Here I couldn't get the complete data.
```

I have mentioned above in the output, I need to get the complete data one by one.
What I need to do? Share your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just loaded the first `Data` element. You got to get all the `Data` elements.

What you need to do is:

```
Element eventDataElement = (Element)parent_ele.getElementsByTagName("EventData").item(0);  // Load the first <EventData> element

NodeList listOfData = eventDataElement.getElementsByTagName("Data"); // Load all the elements with <Data> tag  

// Iterate through each <Data> tag
for(int i = 0; i < listOfData.getLength(); i++) { 

    Element data = (Element)listOfData.item(i);  // Get the i'th <Data> element  

    System.out.println("Data --> "+ data.getTextContent()); // Print the text content.
}
```

### FYI

`NodeList` class is from the `org.w3c.dom` package.

Comment: Hai @Aditya Singh, I got this error "The method getElementsByTagName(String) is undefined for the type Element" and "The method getTextContent(String) is undefined for the type Element". Is it anything need to add.